# Model one entity with one or two tables?

Tags: sql

I have a the following use case where I want to model accounting accounts.

The **Accounts** can be

- External if they are assigned to a client.
- Internal if they are not assigned to a client.

There must exist a many to many relation bewteen external and internal accounts, where one external account can be mapped to one internal account and one internal account can be mapped to many external accounts.

The accounts whether they are external or internal should have the same columns, except for the external that should have a clientId foreign key.

Should I create?

**Option A**: 2 tables for accounts (ExternalAccount, InternalAccount) and 1 table for the mapping (AccountMapping)

or

**Option B**: 1 table for accounts (Account) and 1 table for the mapping (AccountMapping)? external accounts would have clientId defined, and internal would have clientId=NULL

With option A, it's easier to restrict the mapping in the AccountMapping table, any of the foreign keys refers to a different table and entity.

With option B, how could I restrict in the AccountMapping table that 2 external accounts cannot be linked together?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this...

Table ***CUSTOMERS***

| CUST_ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Name for 101 |
| 102 | Name for 102 |
| 103 | Name for 103 |
| ... | ... |

Table ***ACCOUNTS***

| ACC_ID | ACC_TYPE | CUST_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | INTERNAL | null |
| 222222 | EXTERNAL | 101 |
| 333333 | EXTERNAL | 102 |
| 444444 | INTERNAL | null |
| 555555 | INTERNAL | null |
| 666666 | EXTERNAL | 103 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Table ***ACCOUNTS_LINKS***

| LINK_ID | ACC_ID_EXT | ACC_ID_INT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 222222 | 111111 |
| 2 | 333333 | 111111 |
| 3 | 666666 | 444444 |
| ... | ... | ... |

You can get all combined data from tables like here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.ACC_ID, a.ACC_TYPE, 
    c.CUST_ID "CUST_ID", c.CUST_NAME "CUST_NAME",
    CASE WHEN a.CUST_ID Is Null THEN Null ELSE al1.ACC_ID_INT END "ACC_ID_INT"
FROM
    ACCOUNTS a
LEFT JOIN
    ACCOUNTS_LINKS al1 ON(
                            (al1.ACC_ID_EXT = a.ACC_ID And ACC_TYPE = 'EXTERNAL')
                          OR
                            (al1.ACC_ID_INT = a.ACC_ID And ACC_TYPE = 'INTERNAL')
                        )
LEFT JOIN
    CUSTOMERS c ON(c.CUST_ID = a.CUST_ID)
ORDER BY 
    a.ACC_ID, c.CUST_ID
```

In above CASE expressiom I used CUST_ID to determine the type of account and in JOIN condition the ACC_TYPE is used. This is just an example and it can be any way that suits your context the best.
R e s u l t :

| ACC_ID | ACC_TYPE | CUST_ID | CUST_NAME | ACC_ID_INT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | INTERNAL |  |  |  |
| 222222 | EXTERNAL | 101 | Name for 101 | 111111 |
| 333333 | EXTERNAL | 102 | Name for 102 | 111111 |
| 444444 | INTERNAL |  |  |  |
| 555555 | INTERNAL |  |  |  |
| 666666 | EXTERNAL | 103 | Name for 103 | 444444 |

Regards...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's the approach i like the most. But how would you do so in ACCOUNTS_LINKS, cannot be added an internal account in ACC_ID_EXT and an external account in ACC_ID_INT columns?

Comment: When inserting records into ACCOUNTS_LINKS you can check is the ID beeing inserted of type INT or EXT either by the type itself or by presence of a CUST_ID in ACCOUNTS table. That shouldn't be an issue. You can consider creating relationship too with some adjustments if needed. Regards...

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use only one table for this and use boolean etc to mark if it's external/internal. External then has values for foreignKeys, internal has that column value as null/empty.

```
ID | Name | External | ForeignKeys
1  | Internal Account  | 0 | NULL
2  | External Acccount | 1 | 1
```

Restrictions in this case must be done in applications business logic or maybe with an SQL constraint or trigger.

Comment: That would be the Account table, but what about the relation table between accounts? At the moment, I have it like that, but External is an computed column based on the foreign key being null or not.